# Extending UserRole primary key with additional columns ASP.NET Core EF

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, mariadb, pomelo-entityframeworkcore-mysql

I have an ASP.Net Core project with Identity models. It uses a 10.4.17-MariaDB database with the Pomelo MySQL provider. The project is already used in production, but I would like to extend the UserRole with new keys in the latest version. I have defined my own UserRole class that extends the IdentityUserRole like this:

```
public class UserRole : IdentityUserRole<String>
{
    [Key]
    public Guid OrganizationId { get; set; }
    [Key]
    public DateTime Join { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

So I would like my user to have multiple roles in multiple organizations with multiple 'join' dates. I manually added the HasKey line to the entity in DB context:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<UserRole>(entity =>
{
    entity.HasKey(m => new { m.UserId, m.RoleId, m.Join, m.OrganizationId });
    entity.Property(m => m.UserId).HasMaxLength(127);
    entity.Property(m => m.RoleId).HasMaxLength(127);
    entity.Property(m => m.OrganizationId).HasMaxLength(127);
    entity.Property(m => m.Join);
    ...
});
```

When I add a migration with these changes and try to execute it I get the following error:

```
Failed executing DbCommand (31ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
ALTER TABLE `AspNetUserRoles` ADD CONSTRAINT `FK_AspNetUserRoles_AspNetRoles_RoleId` FOREIGN KEY (`RoleId`) REFERENCES `AspNetRoles` (`RoleId`) ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

Why is the migration trying to make a reference to `RoleId` if the primary key of the `AspNetRoles` table is called `Id`?

I checked the first migration with the `Script-Migration` command and the foreign key is correctly referenced to `Id` during the table creation.

Comment: it's strange that the error message says nothing about the cause, it simply means the command is failed. Are you sure you posted all the info? I've never seen such a non-sense sql error.

Comment: The error message itself is longer but I don't think the rest is relevant here. The `ADD CONSTRAINT` command fails because the `RoleId` column in the `AspNetRoles` table doesn't exist. The question is why does the EntityFramework or Pomelo MySQL provider generate such a command? Before extending the class and defining the composite primary key, this statement was `... REFERENCES 'AspNetRoles' ('Id') ON DELETE CASCADE;`

Comment: Please add, what version of Pomelo and EF Core you are using. You might also want to execute the migration (if you are doing it from the command line or package manager) with the `verbose` flag, to get extended error information that you can add to your OP.

Comment: @JakaKordež Have you solved the issue or is this still something you need help with?

Comment: @lauxjpn no I didn't. As I said on Github, I tried with the nightly build but I get a different exception.

Comment: @JakaKordež Found it. The issue on GitHub is [Wrong foreign key reference when creating composite primary key #1371](https://github.com/PomeloFoundation/Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql/issues/1371).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was a bug in the alpha version of the Pomelo library that I used. The bug was already fixed in the nightly build by that time. See the issue [#1371](https://github.com/PomeloFoundation/Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql/issues/1371) on Github.

Answer (score 0):

We have to keep these **two column PK** { u.UserId, u.RoleId } for asp.net core identity managers functionality for example : userManager.AddToRoleAsync()

If you want to have **Id** with **identity:Yes** in UserRole table:

**DbContext** :

```
namespace Attendance.Server.Data;

public class AppDbContext : IdentityDbContext<User, Role, int, UserClaim, UserRole, UserLogin, RoleClaim, UserToken>, IUnitOfWork
{
    public AppDbContext(DbContextOptions<AppDbContext> options) : base(options) { }

    public Task<int> SaveChangesAsync()
    {
        return base.SaveChangesAsync();
    }

    public void MarkAsDeleted<TEntity>(TEntity entity) => base.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Deleted;

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
 modelBuilder.ApplyConfigurationsFromAssembly(typeof(UserConfig).Assembly);
        
    }
}
```

**UserRole** :

```
namespace Attendance.Server.Data.Entities;

public partial class UserRole : IdentityUserRole<int>
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

**UserRoleConfig** :

```
namespace Attendance.Server.Data.Configs;

public class UserRoleConfig : IEntityTypeConfiguration<UserRole>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<UserRole> builder)
    {
        builder.ToTable("UserRole").HasKey(ur => new { ur.Id });
        builder.Property(p => p.Id).ValueGeneratedOnAdd();
        // we have to keep these two column PK for asp.net core identity managers functionality for example : userManager.AddToRoleAsync()
        builder.HasKey(u => new { u.UserId, u.RoleId }); 
        builder.Property(p => p.Id).HasColumnOrder(1);

        // seed
        builder.HasData(
            new UserRole { Id = 1, UserId = 1, RoleId = 1 }
        );
    }
}
```

Then migrate to database:

dotnet ef migrations add createDb -o data/migrations

dotnet ef database update

If you get error on migration delete database by ssms and execute this command again : dotnet ef database update

[image]